# one line match in JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the JavaScript equivalent of this .NET code?

```
var b = Regex.IsMatch(txt, pattern);
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here are the useful functions for working with regexes.

- [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)   A RegExp method that executes a search for a match in a string. It returns an array of information.
- [**`test`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)   A RegExp method that tests for a match in a string. It returns true or false.
- [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) A String method that executes a search for a match in a string. It returns an array of information or null on a mismatch.
- [**`search`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)   A String method that tests for a match in a string. It returns the index of the match, or -1 if the search fails.
- [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) A String method that executes a search for a match in a string, and replaces the matched substring with a replacement substring.
- [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) A String method that uses a regular expression or a fixed string to break a string into an array of substrings.

<sub>Source: [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/core_javascript_1.5_guide/regular_expressions)</sub>

So to answer your question, as the others have said:

```
/pattern/.test(txt)
```

Or, if it is more convenient for your particular use, this is equivalent:

```
txt.search(/pattern/) !== -1
```

Comment: Thanks for Your time and efforts :)

Answer (score 8):

```
var b = /pattern/.test(txt);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts :)

Answer (score 2):

```
/pattern/.test(txt);
```

E.g.:

```
/foo \w+/.test("foo bar");
```

It returns true for a match, just like IsMatch.

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new RegExp(pattern);
var b = regex.test(text);
```

You can also use `var b = /pattern/.test(text)` but then you can't use a variable for the regex pattern.

Comment: No, it's a `ReferenceError`. ;)

Comment: couldn't your correct/one-line this to `var b = (new RegExp(pattern)).test(text);`?

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: Corrected.

Comment: @Mark I was talking about the `/pattern/` syntax.